# List all users and current week entries

Tags: users, user-roles, wp-list-table

Im looking for a simple code to list all users with the role spectator and
if they have made an entry in the current week enter "yes" and if not "no"

Answer (score 1):

If by "made an entry" you mean "has published at least 1 post", then following will do it (with the proviso given below):

```
$args = array (
    'role' => 'spectator',
    ) ;
$spectators = new WP_User_Query ($args) ;

$users_with_recent_posts = array () ;
foreach ($spectators->get_results () as $user) {
    $args = array (
        // if you are interested in posts with a different
        // post_type, then just change the following to
        // be the post_type you're interested in
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'date_query' => array (
            'after' => '7 days ago',
            'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        'author' => $user->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        ) ;
    $posts = new WP_Query ($args) ;
    $users_with_recent_posts[$user->data->user_nicename] = $posts->found_posts > 0 ? 'yes' : 'no' ;
    }
```

**Proviso:** the above will only show a user as `yes` if they have a least 1 post whose `pust_status` is currently `publish`, i.e., if a user published a post within the last 7 days but then that post had it's `post_status` changed to something other than `publish` they will be shown as `no` if that was the only post they published in the last 7 days.

If you mean something else by "made an entry", then please explain what you mean.